# Excel delete previous row if whole value is contained within current row and Column A previous value is same as well

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of computers and users.

- Column A is the names of the computers (with duplicates).
- Column C is a list of the users that I was able to join together in a
  CSV file format.

**Example:**

- In column A, in rows 1 and 2 we have `computer1`.
- In columnc C, row 1 it has `user1` and in row 2 it has `user1,user2`.

I need to keep only the largest row for each computer so that instead of having `Computer1` with `user1` I only have `computer1` with `user1,user2`.

Comment: Are users always separated by commas?

Comment: add a helper column with `=LEN(C2)` then sort on that column descending and use remove duplicates using column A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` to test for an error for all cells below and then use that as a `True`/`False` result. Here's a formula I built:
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,A3:A$999999,0)),"Use Me","ignore")`

[image]

This Macro would also work, if you wanted to delete them:

```
Sub KillRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim killRNG As Range
    Set killRNG = ws.Rows(Rows.Count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(ws.Cells(i + 1, 1), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)), ws.Cells(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            Set killRNG = Union(killRNG, ws.Rows(i))
        End If
    Next i

    killRNG.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```